# Doing a conditional submit

Tags: asp.net

I have a basic asp.net submit button like so:

`<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" onclick="test_Click" />`

I have a javascript method that I want to run before submitting, but I cannot set it up to do so. Anyone know how? The javascript method returns true/false at the end where true = submit.

Thanks for the replies, but I have already tried what you said and it didn't work. Here is my markup:

`<asp:Button OnClientClick="return checkInput();" ID="test" runat="server" onclick="test_Click" />`

The javascript method runs, but even when it returns true the page doesn't post back.

Edit: Nevermind, there was something wrong with the javascript method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define OnClientClick property for that.

```
<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" onclick="test_Click"
onclientclick="if(confirm('Are you sure?')) return true;" />
```

replace the javascript with whatever you want to do, but the above example will only trigger your behind code sub/function [`test_Click`] only after the user clicks YES in the confirm dialog box

Answer (score 1):

If the javascript method should be allowed to cancel the postback and therefore returns `true/false`, you should return that from the `onclientclick` to abort the event if the method returns `false`:

```
<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" 
    OnClientClick="return test_Click();"
    OnClick="Server_Click"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `OnClientClick` to your tag.  Like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="test" runat="server" onclick="test_Click" OnClientClick="**javascript call here**"/>
```

OnClientClick in an asp.net control is the same as an onclick attribute on a regular HTML tag